# How to set standard PHP user permissions?

Tags: php, apache

My PHP-Script creates files and folders.
Like...

```
mkdir("newfolder");
```

Those files'/folders' permissions are automatically set to: *"755"*; the owner and group to: "*www-data*".

When logged in via sftp, i can't delete/modify those folders, because i'm not the user *"www-data"* and even though i'm part of the same group, it would probably need *"775"* permission to allow changes.

So, my question is:

- How can i make PHP to create those folders with my username as
  owner?
- ...or to run as 'myusername' instead of 'www-data'?
- ...or to set *775* as the default permission?

I'm on Debian, Apache2, PHP 5.6.

Comment: The preferred way for this is to set the `umask` of the account www-data, so that files and folders are created with different permissions granting write access to group members. In addition you accept your own user account into the www-data group.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, from what i've found so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0775);
```

should do the trick. mkdir also takes more argument such as allowing recursive create etc. check this out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

hope it helps :)